# PHP Redirect handler - keep URL and URI and fetch content from another URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

You've probably seen it on websites where they offer a website and you can use **your own domain name** if you want. So you register a **www.website.com/user** but you can also set up **yourdomain.com** to redirect [with A record] to **Website_IP_ADDRESS** and they handle it because you gave them your domain (**www.yourdomain.com**) so they know to redirect to **www.website.com/user** but your address bar remains www.yourdomain.com

[krop.com](https://www.krop.com/profile/register/pro/) has it

This is what I've been trying to do:
[image]

I want to be able to handle incoming redirects from multiple websites and 'fetch' content from a subfolder on the main site but keep the original URL intact.

I want to use php since i want to retrieve the user var (bar and foo) from a db.

Since I won't have access to every domain, I can only play with the incoming part (the blue box)

So far I only had success with duplicating a url (www.bar.com fetches 75.333.444.55) which is pretty useless...

And using file_get_contents('http://address') in my index.php to display subfolder index.html without redirecting again but it's slow and browser unfriendly.

I've been trying to ".htaccess it" with little success

Anything will help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want a 302 redirect! You want a virtual host.

Google for virtual host and if you need more help ask - but make sure you tell us what webserver you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
i'm hosting on mediatemple (dv4 - Plesk)


I was able to make a VirtualHost that looks like this:

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/users/foo
  ServerName  www.foo.com
</VirtualHost>

It kinda works but for some reason instead of rendering index.php it downloads it... Uncompiled! Scary! Maybe because it's retrieving the file from the server side (without PHP)
Any idea?

Comment: You presumably don't have php activated. You will need to talk to mediatemple.

Comment: hmmm... it is active because website.com/users/foo/index.php renders just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ariel

here is what happened:
I added the following code to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/users/foo 
ServerName www.foo.com 
ServerAlias *.foo.com
</VirtualHost>

AddHandler php-script   .php
```

Works like charm! :)

Don't forget to restart apache to take effect. On mediatemple it is: /etc/init.d/httpd restart